# Inheritance from the global selector

Tags: html, css, inheritance

```css
* {
  color: yellow
}
.outermost {
  color: blue
}
.middle {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="outermost">
  <div class="middle">
    <p>Some Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect the color of `<p>Some Text </p>` to be red because `<div class="middle">` is its parent. However, the color ends up as yellow. This seems counter-intuitive because the global selector is less specific than the parent container. Why does the `p` element inherit from global, and how can it be changed so that it inherits from the parent container?

Comment: "Universal selector (*), combinators (+, >, ~, ' ') and negation pseudo-class (:not) have no effect on specificity."

Comment: consider the case of `<p>`, it gets one value of property *indirectly* from  `parent tag` and other directly from `* selector` .
Now if you were browser, which one you would prioritize?

The Key point here is that it is irrelevant however strongly parent tag got its property. the parent tag's property will always be lowest in priority line.

Answer (score 2):

As *@j08691* notes in his comment, the universal selector `*` has no effect on specificity:

```css
* {
  color: yellow;
}
.middle {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="middle">
  <p>Some Text</p>
</div>
```

If you'd like the specificity to operate under normal effects change the `*` to `body`:

```css
body {
  color: yellow;
}
.middle {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="middle">
  <p>Some Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: "to allow the color property to flow down the specificty chain while maintaining yellow as the global color if no selector of higher specificity is provided" This statement is misleading. Specificity has nothing to do with whether or not an inherited style is used. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/gv2916jh/2/

Answer (score 1):

You're conflating [inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance) with [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Those aren't the same thing; they're totally unrelated concepts in CSS.

It's true that the global selector has a much lower *specificity* than the `.middle` class selector, but that's irrelevant because the `.middle` selector isn't targeting your `p` element; it's targeting the `p` element's parent.

Normally that would be sufficient to make `p` use red text, because, by default, `p` has its `color` property set to the special value called `inherit`, which causes it to inherit its color from it's parent element. But `p` isn't using the default value (`inherit`) for its color property, because you have a matching rule telling explicitly to use yellow instead:

```
* {
  color: yellow;
}
```

Inheritance doesn't even come into play here, because your `p` element *isn't* set to inherit from it's parent in the first place.

You can override that behavior using a selector with a higher specificity that targets *the element containing your text* (not just one of its ancestors) explicitly telling it to inherit from its parent:

```css
* {
  color: yellow;
}
.outermost {
  color: blue;
}
.middle {
  color: red;
}
.middle > p {
  color: inherit; // This overrides the rule defined by the global selector above
}
```

```html
<div class="outermost">
  <div class="middle">
    <p>Some Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or alternately, you could just stop using the global selector and instead rely on inheritance to set the text color for most of your elements:

```css
body {
  color: yellow;
}
.outermost {
  color: blue;
}
.middle {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outermost">
  <div class="middle">
    <p>Some Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that using the global selector for this sort of thing is usually discouraged anyway, for numerous reasons.

---

To help you better understand why your current code isn't working, here's essentially what it's doing:

```html
<div style="color:blue;"> <!-- Matches * and .outermost. Result: Blue -->
  <div style="color:red;"> <!-- Matches * and .middle. Result: Red -->
    <p style="color:yellow;">Some Text</p> <!-- Matches *. Result: yellow -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: He's not *confusing* inheritance with specificity, per se, he's just not realizing that the declared selector {} takes precedence over the non-declared inherited style). It might be good to point out that, since both the universal selector and inherited styles have a specificity of 0.0.0.0, your example works because the `color: inherit;` property is declared *after* the universal selector's `color: yellow` property. That aside, good answer & explanation; +1

Comment: @TylerH "your example works because the color: inherit; property is declared after the universal selector's color: yellow property" Nope. It's because `.middle > p` has a higher specificity than `*`. Proof: https://jsfiddle.net/xvqk9zzz/2/

Comment: Hmm, seems like that seminal SitePoint article was wrong about the specificity of * and inherited styles both having specificity of 0.0.0.0 then.

Comment: @TylerH Which SitePoint article are you referring to? My understanding is that specificity is unrelated to inheritance. Properties will be inherited from their parent element if their value is set to `inherit` (which, for some properties, is the case by default). If their value is not set to `inherit`, inheritance isn't even considered when determining the property's final, computed value.

Comment: Oops, I meant SmashingMagazine, sorry. Article: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ It mentions at least twice that universal selectors and inherited styles both have a specificity of 0.0.0.0, and doesn't ever clarify that the universal selector does not affect specificity, which would contradict the statement of it having 0.0.0.0 anyway.

Comment: @TylerH Yeah, as far as I know there's actually no such thing as a "inherited selector" outside of a CSS framework like `less` or `sass`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would target the font inside the "middle" class https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/cfckvvzw/3/

```
.middle > p {
  color: red
}
```